# convolutional neural networks for sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was trying to modify YoonKim's code for [sentiment analysis using CNN's.](https://github.com/yoonkim/CNN_sentence) He applies three filters of `heights=[3,4,5]` and `width=300` on

```
input=(batch_size, 1, len(sentence_vector), len(wordVector))
```

I'm stuck after the first `Conv,Pool` computation. Consider

```
input=(batch_size, 1, 64, 300)
```

64 is the length of every sentence vector and 300 is the word embedding size.

```
map=(20, 1, 3, 300)
```

In his implementation, he first applies a kernel of height=3 and width=300. Hence the output would be

```
convolution_output=(batch_size, 20, 62, 1)
```

After which he downsamples using `poolsize=(62, 1)`. The output after MaxPooling becomes

```
maxpool_output=(batch_size, 20, 1, 1)
```

This is where i'm stuck.
In the paper he applies 3 filters of `heights[3,4,5]` and `width=300`. But after applying the first filter, there is no input left for convolution. How(**and on what**) do I apply the second kernel?.

Any help or suggestions would be great. The git page contains a link to the paper.

Comment: Please do not use HTML when posting to Stack Overflow, it uses it's [own syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Mifeet - Thanks for your edits. Will keep that in mind.